# How to load css file using scriptMap in yii?

Tags: css, yii

Im trying use scriptMap in my project!

I have a many `css` files and I want collect all them to one file and load. First I started testing with 2 css files. This files located in `css` folder (`/css/common.css; /css/main.css`). I wrote this code:

```
$cs=Yii::app()->clientScript;
$cs->registerCssFile(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl .'/css/common.css');
$cs->registerCssFile(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl .'/css/main.css');

$cs->scriptMap=array(
    '/css/common.css'=>'/css/all.css',
    '/css/main.css'=>'/css/all.css'
);
```

When I ran this script in HTML source not loaded no `all.css` no another. Where is my error?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$cs->scriptMap=array(
    'common.css'=>'/css/all.css',
    'main.css'=>'/css/all.css'
);
```

Comment: loaded all.css file but this file is empty. I gave to this file permission 766